# How to prove the derivative of the gamma function?

Tags: calculus

How can one prove that the derivative of  $\Gamma(z)$ is $\int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-t} \, t^{z-1} \, \ln(t) \, dt$ ?

Thanks!

Comment: It’s hard to tell what the difficulty is. Do you want to prove that differentiating under the integral sign is valid, or what? I point out that the integrand there is just the derivative of the integrand of the gamma function

Comment: Just take the standard definition of the gamma function and move the differential under the integral sign.

Comment: That's the thing I forgot how to  move the differential under the integral sign, so I am asking for an example

Comment: Well I am hoping someone take the intergral form of the Gamma Function and then shows how one can take the derivative of it which then I could genrealize

Comment: I tried doing that in my last question and it failed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First note that
$$\begin{align}
\Gamma(z) &= \int_0^\infty t^{z-1} e^{-t} dt \\
&= \int_0^\infty e^{(z-1)\cdot (\ln t )} \cdot e^{-t} dt & \text{use identity $a^b = e^{b \cdot \ln a}$} \\
&= \int_0^\infty e^{(z-1)\cdot ( \ln t ) - t} dt.
\end{align}$$
Now, take the derivative.
$$\begin{align}
\frac{d}{dz}\Gamma(z) &= \frac{d}{dz} \int_0^\infty e^{(z-1)\cdot ( \ln t ) - t} dt \\
&= \int_0^\infty \frac{\partial}{\partial z} \left( e^{(z-1)\cdot ( \ln t ) - t} \right) dt & \text{swap derivative and integral} \\
&= \int_0^\infty e^{(z-1)\cdot ( \ln t ) - t} \cdot \frac{\partial}{\partial z} \left( (z-1)\cdot ( \ln t ) - t \right) dt & \text{chain rule} \\
&= \int_0^\infty e^{(z-1)\cdot ( \ln t ) - t} \cdot \ln t\ dt \\
&= \int_0^\infty t^{z-1} e^{-t} \cdot \ln t\ dt \ \checkmark
\end{align}$$

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

> Move the derivative through the integral (there are assumptions needed in order to use this, but suppose for the moment this is allowed without penalty) and use the product rule. Remember that $$\frac{d}{dt} \left( b^t \right) = b^t \ln t.$$

Comment: I think there’s a typo here; it should say $b^t\log b$ instead of $b^t\log t$.